# Retrieve an image to ImageView using Firestore and Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an Identification app that retrieves user information based on user authentication. I have TextViews for information like email, idnumber, etc. I have those displaying based on the uId on sign in. I am trying to show the a picture for that specific person to an ImageView. Also, if another person logs in, their picture will show as well.

This run in Android Studio. Firebase storage has an image with a url. I created a collection of "images" that will correspond by the iud (So the uid is the same for the user and the image) that has a string of the image url.  Below is an image of how its set up.

[image]

[image]

Below is the code:

```
    private ImageView ProfileImage;
private Button logout;



@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userID = user.getUid();

    Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileName);
    Email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
    TwoPNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileUid);
    Meal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mealsNum);
    PantherFunds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pFundsNum);
    Expiration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.expirationDate);
    Campus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.campusText);
    ProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePhoto);



    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            //new
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                toastMessage("Successfully signed in with: " + user.getEmail());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                toastMessage("Successfully signed out.");
            }
            showData();
        }

    };

}

private void showData() {
    DocumentReference user = fireStore.collection("users").document(userID);
    user.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();

                assert doc != null;
                Name.setText(doc.getString("name"));
                Email.setText(doc.getString("email"));
                TwoPNum.setText(doc.getString("twop_num"));
                Meal.setText(String.valueOf(doc.getLong("meals")));
                PantherFunds.setText(String.valueOf(doc.getDouble("pfunds")));
                Expiration.setText(getDate(Long.parseLong("expiration_date")));
                Campus.setText(doc.getString("campus"));
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**My first thought was to create another method ShowImage and have a document reference to Firestore based on the uId, then pull the url of the picture and attach that picture to the ImageView like I did with all of the other User information. Didnt work. **

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) plugin to accomplish this.
You simply provide it a url and an ImageView and it will automagically download and place your image in the view.

Simply add it to your gradle dependency file with:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:(insert latest version)'
```

Or maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.picasso3</groupId>
    <artifactId>picasso</artifactId>
    <version>(insert latest version)</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can use something like this to load the image:

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: It will add it based on the uid? I didnt know that

Comment: You need to use the uid to get the image url from the Firebase db, then use that url in the load() part of picasso.